# Unicode from xls to CSV

Tags: python, excel, csv, unicode, encoding

I'm trying since 2 days to find what is exactly wrong in the following code which convert xls file to CSV file
My issue is that some character are not correctly encoded (é, à...etc) on the output CSV. I already read a ton of post on SOF but i did not find a solution. I know that the problem is coming from the csv module which handle only Ascii or UTF-8 but i don't know how to handle it. 
I used also the replacement module [unicodecsv](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv) without success. I know that there is some example here for unicode [csv unicode example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) but i don't know the correct way to use it.

What i'm sure is that my xls is encode on utf_16_LE (workbook encoding).

Here is the code which i found on SOF also. I tried lot of modification but no way to success. Someone can tell which part of the code is change.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import xlrd
from os import sys
import csv 


def csv_from_excel(excel_file):

    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file)
    print workbook.biff_version, workbook.codepage, workbook.encoding
    #test read of accent charactere
    rs = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    print rs.cell_value(1,0)

    all_worksheets = workbook.sheet_names()
    for worksheet_name in all_worksheets:
        worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)
        your_csv_file = open(''.join([worksheet_name,'.csv']), 'wb')

        class ExcelFr(csv.excel):
        #Separateur de champ
            delimiter = ";"

        csv.register_dialect('excel-fr', ExcelFr())

        wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file,'excel-fr', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

        for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
            wr.writerow([unicode(entry).encode("utf-8") for entry in worksheet.row_values(rownum)])

        your_csv_file.close()

#if __name__ == "__main__":
#    csv_from_excel(sys.argv[1])

csv_from_excel("source-2014-02-12.xls")
```

EDIT: NEW CODE: which only convert the first sheet (i don't need anymre sheets).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import xlrd
import unicodecsv
import codecs

def csv_from_excel(excel_file):

    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file)
    print wb.biff_version, wb.codepage, wb.encoding
    sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Feuil1')
    print sh.row_values(8)
    #your_csv_file = open('your_csv_file.csv', 'wb')
    your_csv_file = codecs.open('your_csv_file.csv','wb')

    class ExcelFr(unicodecsv.excel):
        #Separateur de champ
        delimiter = ";"

    unicodecsv.register_dialect('excel-fr', ExcelFr())

    wr = unicodecsv.writer(your_csv_file,'excel-fr',encoding='utf-8', quoting=unicodecsv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))
        #wr.writerow([unicode(entry).encode("utf-8") for entry in sh.row_values(rownum)])

    your_csv_file.close()

csv_from_excel("source-2014-02-13.xls")


reader = unicodecsv.reader("your_csv_file.csv")
print reader.encoding
```

OUTPUT:

80 1200 utf_16_le
[u'Chaise de massage ergonomique pliante', u'Facile \xe0 monter et ajustable \xe0 tout gabarit et pour tout traitement du haut du corps comme la t\xeate, le dos, les \xe9paules et les bras. Le soutien pour la t\xeate est amovible et ajustable comme l\u2019assise et l\u2019accoudoir. Le massage sur chaise est une mani\xe8re tr\xe8s efficace de stimuler la circulation du sang, de l\u2019\xe9nergie et permet au corps de retrouver un certain \xe9quilibre. A noter que la chaise peut \xe9galement \xeatre utilis\xe9e comme chaise de tatouage. ', u'Fauteuil de massage blanc, pliant et facile \xe0 transporter..... etc etc
utf-8

As you can see there are character like i say '\xe0' or '\u2019'

I still don't understand all mess around the encoding things!

Comment: Is that Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, this is wrong:

```
your_csv_file = open(''.join([worksheet_name,'.csv']), 'wb')
```

The standard Python `open()` function opens binary files, so you need to make sure the data is properly encoded yourself. You should import the `codecs` module and use:

```
your_csv_file = codecs.open(''.join([worksheet_name,'.csv']), 'w', 'utf-8')
```

I agree with you that `unicode(entry).encode("utf-8")` should have the same effect, though.

If my suggestion doesn't help, then you need to tell us exactly why you think "some character are not correctly encoded".

Comment: hi, thanks for your help: here is the source xls file (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49503438/source-2014-02-12.xls) when i use codecs.open method then i get: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just dont understand what you are seeing

open idle and enter

`print u" mani\xe8re tr\xe8s"`   \x## is simply a hex digit that has no ascii representation,

`print u"l\u2019assise et l\u2019accoudoir"` will demonstrate that \u#### is simply a unicode character that has no reperesentation

Comment: I tried already lot of encodings during the writing method but still blocked.

Comment: Thx Joran, Actually I know this hex digit but what did not understand it's why when i opened it with excel it show those character. I will make some test live on my server to see how there looks when i read the csv file.